# Problem debugging on dap-mode

Tags: debugging, lsp-mode, lsp, debug, dap

I am new to emacs and I was following this tutorial to configure lsp-mode:

https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide/

But dap-debug does not work. Everytime I try to debug, it doesn't stop at any breakpoint and it shows up this message:

```
1[1] + Done "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-96ov4rxz.d3n" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-dcuobbae.cqc"


Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555169 in main ()
[Inferior 1 (process 19914) exited normally]
```

I've tried changing the launch template many times but nothing worked.

my init file

```lisp
(setq package-selected-packages '(lsp-mode yasnippet helm-lsp
                       projectile hydra flycheck company avy which-key helm-xref dap-mode))

(when (cl-find-if-not #'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (mapc #'package-install package-selected-packages))

(which-key-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'lsp)

(setq gc-cons-threshold (* 100 1024 1024)
      read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)
      treemacs-space-between-root-nodes nil
      company-idle-delay 0.0
      company-minimum-prefix-length 1
      lsp-idle-delay 0.1)  ;; clangd is fast

(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
  (require 'dap-cpptools)
  (yas-global-mode))
(tooltip-mode 1)
(dap-ui-controls-mode 1)

(setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-l")
```

my launch template:

```json
(dap-register-debug-template
  "cpptools::Run Configuration"
  (list :type "cppdbg"
        :request "launch"
        :name "cpptools::Run Configuration"
        :MIMode "gdb"
        :program "${workspaceFolder}/main"
        :cwd "${workspaceFolder}"))
```

Things I've already added to launch template:

```json
(dap-register-debug-template
  "MyCdebug"
  (list :type "cppdbg"
        :request "launch"
        :name "MyCdebug"
        :MIMode "gdb"
        :program "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        :dap-compilation "cd '${workspaceFolder}' && gcc ${fileBasename} -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension} -lm -lgmp && '${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}'"
        :dap-compilation-dir "${workspaceFolder}"
        :cwd "${workspaceFolder}"
        :args ["-fdiagnostics-color=always -g '${file}' -o '${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}'"]
        :stopOnEntry "false"
        :TargetArchitecture "x86_64"
        :additionalSOLibSearchPath "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
        :symbolSearchPath "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"))
```

Comment: Suggest two things: modify the variable ```:stopOnEntry``` to ```true```, and then set some breakpoints. Take care the compiler may optimise the code, so in some instances even if you set a breakpoint, it cannot be reached. Another thing is to use a ```launch.json```  file in the project root (is that launch.json used in vscode).

Comment: See this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux - look for the file ```launch.json``` - there are some small inaccuracy in your settings - e.g. you fail to pass the switch ```-g``` to compilation, to generate debug symbols; if your file is ```.cpp```,
then the compiler call should be ```g++```; at debugger level the parameter ```"args":``` should
be ```[]```, i.e. it refers to arguments passed to main at startup, not arguments for compiling.

Comment: There is an Emacs package ```compile``` which can be used for compilation, by default uses
```make``` utility, but can be configured for some other commands. I observed that debug
templates shown uses a small number of parameters and they be in the specified order, so
it is a good idea to use a ```.json``` launch file instead, but decision is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ian](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12077/ian) said I needed to pass the `-g` switch to the compilation, now the breakpoints are working. Thank you.

```
:dap-compilation "cd '${workspaceFolder}' && gcc ${fileBasename} -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension} -g -lm -lgmp && '${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}'"
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to include the code snippet you updated for the benefit of future readers?  Thanks!